# How to print multiple variable in Ruby controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am totally new in ruby. My Ruby version 2.2. I have an edit profile form. I want to show both the table and form data in two different different place. Please check my code

**users_controller.rb**

```
def edit_profile
    @user = User.get_profile(session[:user_id])
    raise $user.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
          if params[:user][:avatar]
            params[:user][:photo] = orginal_file_upload params[:user][:avatar]
          end
          raise params.inspect
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :my_profile }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
     end
end
```

Here I have define `raise $user.inspect` and `raise params.inspect` I want to get both data. But here in my page only coming first one. Please check and let me know how to get my both array value.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want them to appear on the page or in the logs?

Comment: Where do you want to print it? `raise` is not for printing, but for "raising errors".

Comment: Want to appear my two array values in my page

Comment: Use Rails.logger.info params, instead of raise to print both the values.

Comment: @Uzbekjon I want to print in the `users_controller` I don't know what is the exact coding for print. I know php very well there are `print_r` and `echo` for print result. But I don't know in Ruby.

Comment: that's a controller, not a view, how could you get the first one anyway? and, use raise?!!

Comment: Look at guides "Debugging Rails Applications" section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: There is one more useful tool to debug: **RailsPanel** https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise` is a mechanism of throwing errors. `raise $user.to_s` returns the control out of action. You can use `puts` method to display the values in controller.

**The correct code will be:**

```
def edit_profile
@user = User.get_profile(session[:user_id])

respond_to do |format|
      if params[:user][:avatar]
        params[:user][:photo] = orginal_file_upload params[:user][:avatar]
      end

      @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { render :inline => "User<p> ID:<%= @user.id %><br>NAME: <%= @user.name %><br>EMAIL: <%= @user.email %></p>Params <p><%= params.inspect%></p>".html_safe }


 end
end
```

Comment: `puts @user.to_s` unable to print any record.

Comment: use `@user.inspect` instead

Comment: in your code you are using `$user` make sure the object is not empty

Comment: I am not sure object empty or not. But if i `raise @user.inspect`  and `raise params.inspect` individually this is working fine. But not showing both result at a time.

Comment: `raise` will always work. It trows the exception. Whereas `puts` only print the string to console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109532/discussion-between-chinu-and-zaingz).

Comment: Thanks for your answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign them to instance variables like `@user` and `@params` and access them in your views. Having said that you already have assigned `@user` variable and `params` is accessible in your views automatically.

```
# In your view
<%= @user.name %>

<%= params %>
```

Also, consider making your controller RESTful. You can send `PUT` request to your controllers URL (eg. `PUT profile/1`) it will automatically call your `ProfileController#edit` method.

Comment: I want to print in controller. Not view

Comment: But you said: "*Want to appear my two array values in my page*". So do  you want it on your page or in your console? If you want it in your webpage, then you have to print it in your view.

Comment: Yes page means not view. my controller `echo` will show in my browser.

Comment: @Chinu not in Rails! At most, you can do `render plain: @user`. There are other types you can use with `render` (json, xml, body, etc.).

Comment: `render plain: [@user.inspect, params.inspect].join`